# Alternator wear due to bad battery

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, batteries, electrical-engineering

I recently heard that a bad car battery (I assume "bad" means it drains faster than it was designed to) will wear out your [alternator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternator) faster.

How is this possible?

Please note I am not looking for an answer like "It puts more stress on the alternator". I want to better understand how a generator can experience more wear when the *only* mechanical input variables (torque and revolutions per minute) stay the same.

Comment: Would [mechanics.se] or [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: If a bad battery required more current draw, that will increase the counter torque of the alternator which the car motor must overcome. That will change the mechanical loading of the thrust and roller bearings in the alternator. The higher current draw also increases the heating of the voltage regulator diodes. Both of these factors will increase wear.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in Motor Vehicle & Maintenance.

Comment: @BillN could you please explain the mechanical loading part? wouldnt the motors torque and rpm via the belt be fixed and if the alternator needs more torque, the belt would simply slip? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is actually [on Stack Exchange already](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/27815/can-a-weak-battery-destroy-an-alternator).  It's on the Motor Vehicle site.  The version there is more complete than the one I present here.

The general synopsis is that if a generator has to provide more power, it must have more torque applied to it.  This is simply conservation of energy.  If you want more power out of the generator, you need to put more  in.

A "bad battery" tends to dissipate power.  It's like putting a small resistor in the circuit.  A really bad one can draw a *lot* of current.

The failure mode is more obvious when you consider that the generator has some feedback elements to it.  Alternators can adjust the current they produce by varying the magnetic fields generated by the electromagnets in the alternator.  More current to the electromagnets means more powerful magnetic fields, which means more current generated.  There's regulatory circuitry to support this.

With a bad battery, the circuitry has to run the alternator with a very high magnetic field to keep up with the battery's ability to sink current.  At low RPMs, this means you generate a lot of energy to support the battery, but your cooling (from fans tied to the revolutions of the engine) is weak.  This leads to the alternator running hot, and eventually wearing those hot mechanical components faster.